# Is there a way I can create a loop so that my script restarts after completion?

Tags: powershell

Here is my script to run message traces by sender address. I want to have it set up in a way that it will re-run the `Get-MessagesBySender` function so you can go ahead and run a new message trace after the previous one has completed. I am fairly new to PowerShell so any ideas will be brilliant! :)

```
# SCRIPT TO RUN MESSAGE TRACES BY THE SENDER ADDRESS

Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName email@address.com | cls

Get-MessagesBySender

function Get-MessagesBySender {

# Input by user -------------------------------------------
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [int]$Days,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$MailSender,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$DeliveryStatus,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$OutputFile
    )

# Pass input by user to the command's variables -----------
[DateTime]$DateStart = (Get-Date).AddDays($Days * -1)
[DateTime]$DateEnd = (Get-Date)

Write-Information $MailSender
Write-Information $DeliveryStatus
Write-Information $OutputFile

# Message Traces ------------------------------------------
$Messages = Get-MessageTrace -StartDate $DateStart -EndDate $DateEnd -SenderAddress $MailSender -Status $DeliveryStatus | Select-Object -Property Received, SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, Subject, Status

# Exporting the data --------------------------------------
$Messages | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation

# Completed Status ----------------------------------------
Write-Host -NoNewLine "Trace completed. The results have been saved in: $OutputFile." -ForegroundColor Green

}

# END SCRIPT
```

Comment: `while ($true) {Get-MessageySender}` will loop the function infinitely, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Brilliant! This works thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop it infinitely by putting your code in a `while ($true)` loop so it loops untill broken by `break` like

```
while ($true) {Get-MessageySender}
```